# getting "uninitialized constant ApplicationController" in rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to learn `Rails 4` framework and followed official [doc](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html)

I ran these following commands:

```
rails new fold
```

It created a new project

```
rails generate controller home index
```

It generate a `home_controller` and `views/home/index.html.erb`

Content of `home_controller` :

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
 def index
 end
end
```

For routing I added following code in `routes.rb`

```
 get 'home/index' => 'home#index'
```

After running the application I am getting :

```
uninitialized constant ApplicationController
```

What I am doing wrong here? Here is the `Stacktrace`

```
app/controllers/home_controller.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `const_get'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:261:in `block in constantize'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `each'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `inject'
activesupport (4.2.4) lib/active_support/inflector/methods.rb:259:in `constantize'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:72:in `controller_reference'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:62:in `controller'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:41:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.4) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:821:in `call'
```

What is the wrong with the code?

Comment: Do you have `application_controller.rb` in `app/controllers`? If not you should have it.

Comment: Oops! I removed it. Do I need to include it is it something related to  `HomeController < ApplicationController`

Comment: Yes you should include it.

Comment: Where I will get the code for `ApplicaitonCOntroller`?

Answer (score 5):

Do you have an ***application.rb*** file? This file should be sitting inside of ***app/controllers***. All of the other controllers inherit from this controller. The most minimal setup would look like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this:

```
#app/controllers/home_controller.rb
class HomeController < ActionController::Base
  def index
  end
end
```

This should fix it temporarily.

--

To fix it permanently, you should add the following file to your app:

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
   def index
   end
end
```

You should also change your `home_controller` back to the following:

```
#app/controllers/home_controller.rb
class HomeController < ApplicationController
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Application controller should contain this

app/controllers/application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception

end
```

Answer (score 0):

> uninitialized constant ApplicationController

You should have `application_controller.rb` in `app/controllers` because 
`ApplicationController` is practically the class which ***every other controller*** in your application is going to inherit from (although this is not mandatory in any mean).

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
# Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
# For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
end
```